# Proving Index Law for negative power

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

I came across a proof in [this book](https://archive.org/stream/AnIntroductionToAbstractAlgebra-Volume1/Hall-AnIntroductionToAbstractAlgebraVol1#page/n113) which shows that $(x^m)^n=x^{mn}$ where $n=-k$ and $m$ is a positive integer but there's a step that I am having trouble justifying. The proof is as follows:
\begin{align}
(x^m)^n&=(x^m)^{-k}\\
&=((x^m)^{-1})^k \\
&=((x^{-1})^m)^k \\
&=(x^{-1})^{mk} \\
&=x^{-mk}\\
&=x^{mn}
\end{align}
I don't get how they justified going from line 2 to 3. The author said by "the rule for the inverse of a product" which is shown on page 209 but I don't see the connection. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

$(x^{-1})^m\cdot x^m=$

$(x^{-1}(x^{-1}(....... (x^{-1}\cdot x).....)x)x) $ by associativity.

And by induction that is equal to the identity.

So $(x^m)^{-1}=(x^{-1})^m$

......

Or.  By inverse product $(ab)^{-1}=b^{-1}a^{-1} $ so $(x^m)^{-1}=(xxxxxxx.....xxx)^{-1}=x^{-1} x^{-1} x^{-1}... x^{-1} x^{-1} x^{-1}= (x^{-1})^m $.

Answer (score 0):

The justification is as follows-

Consider some $x\gt 0$.

Then, ${1\over x^{m}}= {1^{m}\over x^{m}}, m\in \mathbb{N}$ (Since, $1^{m}=1$ for all $m\in \mathbb{N}$)

$\Rightarrow {1\over x^{m}}=( {1\over x})^{m}$ (Since, ${a^{m}\over b^{m}}=({a\over b})^{m}$ for all positive integral $m$)

It should be obvious that the above is equivalent to -

$(x^{m})^{-1}=(x^{-1})^{m}$ as required.

The steps in the justification follow from the power laws for positive integral indices, with which you must undoubtedly be familiar.

Comment: Hmm... At first you say "$m\in\mathbb N$", then " for all real $m$" and then "for all positive integral $m$".

Comment: @manooooh  See the edit and thanks for pointing this out :D